# Passing Parameter into function match

Tags: javascript, regex, match, web-deployment

I am using the function match for a search engine, so whenever a user types a search-string I take that string and use the match function on an array containing country names, but it doesn't seem to work.

For example if I do :

```
var string = "algeria";
var res = string.match(/alge/g); //alge is what the user would have typed in the search bar
alert(res);
```

I get a string `res = "alge"`: //thus verifying that alge exists in algeria

But if I do this, it returns null, why? and how can I make it work?

```
var regex = "/alge/g";
var string = "algeria";
var res = string.match(regex);
alert(res);
```

Answer (score 3):

To make a regex from a string, you need to create a RegExp object:

```
var regex = new RegExp("alge", "g");
```

(Beware that unless your users will be typing actual regular expressions, you'll need to escape any characters that have special meaning within regular expressions - see [Is there a RegExp.escape function in Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3561493/is-there-a-regexp-escape-function-in-javascript) for ways to do this.)

Comment: Was just typing the same.  In the original post var regex = "/alge/g" is a string, not a regular expression :)

Answer (score 0):

You don't need quotes around the regex:

```
var regex = /alge/g;
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove the quotes around the regex.

```
              var regex = /alge/g;
              var string = "algeria";
              var res = string.match(regex);
              alert(res);
```

Answer (score 0):

found the answer, the match function takes a regex object so have to do

```
             var regex = new RegExp(string, "g");
            var res = text.match(regex);
```

This works fine